# What does it mean to solve an expression in terms of a variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If i have this:

$a + p = 3$, what means express in terms of $a$? , I know that this is elementary, and although I know how to do more difficult things, I have overlooked it.

Comment: "Express $p$ in terms of $a$" means that you have $p=\underbrace{3-a}$ where on the left of the equals sign is the variable you want to express (*in this case $p$*) and on the right of the equals sign is a function where the variable we are expressing does not appear, but rather is a function of the other variable.

Comment: What is correct ? your answer or @vadim123 answer

Comment: JMoravitz is correct.  vadim123 solved *for* a *in terms of* p.  JMoravitz solved *for* p *in terms of* a.  "In terms of a" means that $a$ is treated as a constant and something *else* is solved in terms of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a + p = 3 \iff a= 3 - p \iff p=3-a$.

To express something "in terms of" variables, is to have an expression with variables in which the variables, although unknown, are considered constants.

"$a+p$" is an expression "in terms of $a$ and $p$".  If we *knew* what $a$ and $p$ were that expression would simply be a single value

"$3-p$" is an expression "in terms of $p$".  And "$3-a$" is an expression "in terms of $a$" for the same reasons.

To solve something is to state:  "I know what IT is:  IT = $blahblahblah$"

$a + p = 3$ is a "solution" for $a + p$.  We know exactly what $a + p$ is (unfortunately we don't know what either $a$ are $p$ individually are.)

$p = 3-a$ is a "solution" for $p$.  We know that $p$ is definitely $3-a$.  Now, you might point out that we don't actually know what $p$ is precisely because we don't actually know what $a$ is.  And that's true.

This is a solution "in terms of $a$".  We don't know what $p$ *objectively* is, but we do know what it is "in terms of $a$".  Whatever $a$ is.... $p$ is going to be $3$ minus that.

Likewise $a = 3-p$ is a solution *for* $a$ *in terms of* $p$.